# Search value in db with appended value - Codeigniter

Tags: php, search, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter.

Using Active Records to run the query.

I have a search box to search for keywords.

I have appended a prefix before the return query id number in the view. eg: 1 = bk001.

How do I search for 'bk001' I can search for bk001 by typing "1" but I would like have bk001 searchable

```
   $query =  $this->db->select('id, name, title')
                ->from('books')
                ->like('name', $search)
                ->or_like('id', $search);


    $ret['rows'] = $query->get()->result();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to format it like a normal like query so

```
$query =  $this->db->select('id, name, title')
            ->from('books')
            ->like('name', $search)
            ->or_like('id', "%$search");

$ret['rows'] = $query->get()->result();
```

Will return `bk001`, `bk011`, `bksidfhskdfhks31` (so as long as it ends it 1).

```
$query =  $this->db->select('id, name, title')
            ->from('books')
            ->like('name', $search)
            ->or_like('id', "%$search%");

$ret['rows'] = $query->get()->result();
```

will return if a 1 is found **ANYWHERE** in the id.

Note that I am assuming you only want this for id, If you want it for name you will still need to modify name.